# Get hystrix timeout exception

Tags: timeout, hystrix

Is there a way to get exceptions that come from hystrix and not your `run` code? When I call `getFailedExecutionException()` in `getFallback()`, the exception is null if it's caused by something like a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup hystrix to use Semaphore ? If it is the case, then you should use thread instead.